# Webpack script in index

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I recently finished to add Webpack to my Angular2 web application and I have an issue with some external libraries variables.

I want to use for example moment.js and I need to declare moment, I used to do it like `declare var moment` but after the webpack transition I had to add a script import to get it, so `<script src="./../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>`

The thing is when I want to build the app to be deployed in test or prod, it still tries to import the JS file from `./../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js` which doesn't exist anymore.

Do anyone know how to make it work so it works for non minified environment in local + minified for test/prod? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using webpack but not importing moment.js through npm by an import or require statement?

Comment: I get it through npm as it's in the package.json then in my node_modules folder, but I must admit I don't know where I should get it with a require in my Angular2 app then how to declare var moment with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be requiring moment.js in a main or app.ts file.

```
import 'moment';
```

Comment: That was just it... Sometimes it's the easiest way, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppose to manually grab the javascript with a script tag from the node_modules folder. NPM and webpack are specificially set up for you so you can import the javascript from a node_module with either 'require' or 'import'.

Using either of those, they will dive into your node_modules folder and look for a corresponding package.

```
import Moment as 'moment';
```

Using this bit of code above, you will set a variable of `Moment` to the javascript you have grabbed from the node_modules folder.

What particular javascript you are grabbing the that folder depends on the package.json that each node module has. To learn a bit more about this you can take a quick look on how to create a node module yourself:

https://quickleft.com/blog/creating-and-publishing-a-node-js-module/

The getting started documentation of webpack should also help you out. They describe the entire process but instead of using moment.js they use lodash(another NPM package):

https://webpack.js.org/guides/get-started/

The "creating a bundle" part should help you get on your way.